Нельзя на данном сайте писать эмоциональные вопросы и ответы?
Нельзя на данном сайте  писать эмоциональные вопросы и ответы?

что имеется ввиду под "эмоциональными вопросами и ответами"?

не то, что нельзя, но эмоции субъективны. Это оценка и восприятие конкретного персонажа. Я к сожалению не увидел вопрос, но судя по цитатам в ответе, ничего криминального там не было. Мы привыкли работать с задачами, которые требуют решения. И им, этим задачам, абсолютно все равно злимся/радуемся/рыдаем мы над ними или нет. Просто надо решить. Из этого и стоит исходить. Вы задаете вопрос -> вы хотите решить задачу -> кратчайший путь - дать сухую информацию. Есть вот "это", должно быть "так-то", а происходит "вот это". "Что не так?"

Можно (если репа больше 30000)

На мой взгляд всё, что не относится к вопросу не должно в нём присутствовать. Эмоции, проклятья, причитания, излишне эпистолярный стиль вопроса, пространные рассуждения о смысле бытия не сделают вопрос более понятным и лаконичным, но своими эмоциональными/ненужными "деталями" может вызвать нежелаемую реакцию/ответ.
Хорошо составленный вопрос - это уже половина ответа.

Спорно. В любом случае, это будет где-то на грани и каждый случай будет индивидуален - так что лучше не надо. Ну и наверное, не стоит ходить по грани имея рейтинг 27.

Ну и, если я правильно понимаю, ты на самом деле хочешь узнать про этот вопрос? В нём вообще нет полезной информации - только код. Непонятно, какое поведение ожидается, непонятно, какое поведение фактически происходит.
В принципе, фразы

Данный код хочет дать мне люлей.
Окно начинает вести себя ПСИХИЧЕСКИМ НЕ ЗДОРОВЫМ.

сами по себе странные, но вроде бы и не оскорбление. Весьма вероятно, что при наличии полезной информации в вопросе, их бы просто переписали или удалили (при наличии достаточной репутации правки может вносить любой пользователь и я почти уверен, что желающий их внести на сайте бы нашёлся), но при её отсутствии правки бесполезны.
Вот, я когда-то задавал похожий вопрос - тоже стандартный контрол, который повёл себя странно просто во всём, что я от него хотел, но у меня конкретный список пунктов, что не так, плюс скринвидео по ним. Наверное, формально этот вопрос тоже не очень соответствует правилам сайта, тем не менее, у него на данный момент рейтинг +7 -0 и никто никогда не голосовал за закрытие.
У твоего вопроса рейтинг +0 -3 и 4 голоса за закрытие (для закрытия требуется 5).

Ну и заодно, что касается этого вопроса. Сама идея вопроса не плохая, но как и написали в первом же комментарии ответ на этот вопрос сложный. Стиль кое-как заданного вопроса (текст неграмотный, даже пример кода написан с ошибкой - пропущена круглая скобка) с полностью отсутствующим описанием, что именно под этим понимается и почему это важно, не располагает к написанию большого подробного ответа, который, автор-новичок (в питоне) скорее всего не оценит. Однако, я скорее не понимаю тех, кто голосовал против. Т. е. я частично их понимаю - кое-как написанный вопрос вполне логично собирает минусы, но всё же на мой взгляд этот вопрос не так ужасен, особенно после правки. Впрочем, я не знаю, ставились ли голоса до правки или после. С закрытием аналогично - большая вероятность того, что ты хотел узнать далеко не то, что спросил, поэтому закрытие в некоторой степени логично, но я бы закрывать не стал.
